# Windows Keras Install error - Import error occurred. No module named queue

Tags: python, keras

I am running the below Anaconda distribution:

```
print(sys.version)
2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:12:11) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

I have got Theano (0.7.0) installed, which works fine. I have downloaded and unzipped the Keras distribution (as I cannot do pip due to firewall restrictions).
I run

```
python setup.py install
```

which installs Keras. When it comes to importing it, the below line does not throw an error:

```
import Keras as kr
```

However, `from keras.models import Sequential` throws the error:

```
Import error occurred. No module named queue.
```

When I try to run `Sequential` as below, this time it cannot find `models`.

```
model = kr.models.Sequential()
error: 'module' object has no attribute 'models'
```

Does anyone know what can be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of your information is too little,I could only specify my suspect.

1、"Environment Path"
I suppose you had a old python version in addition to anaconda python,and the old version python isn't removed from the environment path,so when you exec the command "python setup.py install" ,the keras was installed in old python site-package

2、"install failed"
the core problem is this sentence "from keras.models import Sequential"
when you can't compile this, this next error "'module' object has no attribute 'models'" must be thrown.the first error pointed out the module queue missing, you install it in addition.

otherwise,reinstall all the module,you can try this procedure:

- Install Anaconda x64.
- run conda update conda
- run conda update --all
- run conda install mingw libpython
- pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git

  you can git clone then python install
- pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git